# jquery keeping count of dynamically added/removed elements

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of jQuery that generates a "div" when a button is pressed.  There is a limit of 10 "div"s per page.  The counter works, but when I delete one, it doesn't quite work the way I want it to. When one is deleted, and I continue adding, it duplicates the last number.

For example if I create 6 "div"s and delete #4 leaving 5 divs, then I add another div, I will again have 6 divs, but I will have 2 "div"s labeled 6.

Is there a better way to manage counters?

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
$("#objectivesGroup").sortable();
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAddObjective").on("click" ,function () {
    if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
        return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'objective' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
        "<div>test</div><input type='button' value='delete'>");
    counter++;
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeObjective', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    counter--;
});
});
```

Comment: Are you using the id? if not, just count how many objects you have before adding a new one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a queue of unused numbers.
Start off with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
When you are creating a new item, check if there is a value left in the queue and if there is, pop it off and use it. If you remove an item, re-add it's value to the queue.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to just 'count' the current number of elements that match your class rather than maintaining the counter variable.

`var currentNumberOfDiv = $('.removeObjective').length;`

note: This will only work for you if you DO NOT actually need the unique ID values for the added elements.

Answer (score 1):

This what you want is to loop through the remaining learning objective (after deleting one/some), and
- renumber them
- reassign IDs
- pick up the count at the right number

Following code does the above

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAddObjective").on("click" ,function () {
    if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
        return false;
    }
    $(this).parent().append("<div id='objective'"+counter+"'>"+counter+"<input type='button' value='delete' class='removeObjective'></div>");
    counter++;
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeObjective', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    counter--;
    resetStuff();
})

function resetStuff() {
    counter = 1;
    $(".removeObjective").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().attr('id','objective'+counter);
        $(this).parent().text(counter).append('<input type="button" value="delete" class="removeObjective">');
        counter++;
    })
}
});
```